# Unable to disabled the dropdown as it is passing as input parameter

Tags: angular, typescript

We are working with PrimeNG and angular 15.

**Scenarios:** As per requirement we need to disable the primeNG dropdown control based on the selection.

**Problem:** The disabled property of <p.dropdown> was not working as expected. If we pass disbaled:true actually the dropdown should be get disabled. But in my case it is not getting disabled.

**Explanation:**
We created one dropdown reusable component with one input property as per client requirement using PrimeNG control<p.dropdown>.

**show-dropdown.component.html**

```
<p-dropdown [disabled]="disable”>Value</p-dropdown>
```

**Show-dropdown.component.ts**

```
import {Input,OnInit,Output,} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-show-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './show-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-dropdown.component.scss'],
})
export class ShowDropdownComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()   disabled: boolean
}
```

We reused this "show-dropdown" in another component as below.

**Display-dropdown.component.html**

```
<app-show-dropdown  [disabled]="true"></app-show-dropdown>
```

When i try to run the application the dropdown is working fine. But the disabled property is not working as expected.

It is showing following message in browser console.

```
It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
  when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
  you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.

  Example:
  // Specify the `disabled` property at control creation time:
  form = new FormGroup({
    first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
    last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
  });

  // Controls can also be enabled/disabled after creation:
  form.get('first')?.enable();
  form.get('last')?.disable();
```

I tried to resolved it by using [attr.disabled] as parameter. still the issue is coming.

Request for suggestions how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you are trying to disable the form control using an attribute which would be how you do it for a Template Driven Form.

For a reactive form, (one that uses the FormControlName directive) you should set it programatically.

```
this.form.get('controlName').disable();
```

given that this is linked to the disabled input you should probably add an ngOnChanges function that listens and updates accordingly.

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
   // Can check here to see if disabled changed, then disable or enable as needed
   this.form.get('controlName').disable();
}
```

Its also worth noting that Angular provides an interface you can implement called ControlValueAccessor when creating custom form components. I wont go into detail here but there are plenty of good articles out there which are worth a read.

All that being said do you need to wrap this in a custom component, might be easier to just use the primeNg dropdown directly?